# Microsoft Dynamics CRM for phones "Not authorized to use this app" - IOS

Tags: ios, mobile, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have has an issue with my organization not being able to log into the Dynamics CRM app.

i tried to re-install the app many times, made sure the "CRM for mobile" option was selected in the Business management tab of their security role, as well as making sure they had full access to "System Application Metadata" under the Customization tab of their security role. I had not used the apps under any other organization and so all of the support threads i had came to a dead end.

When starting the app for the first time it would show the "tip" screen but with no writing below it (normally would say something like "5/5 processing metadata")

[image]

waiting long enough or trying to go back into this would generate an error that they were not authorized (even for me who was system administrator)

[image]

I am running CRM online 2016 with iPhone 5S

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please post this in a more appropriate place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much re-installing and mucking around with security roles, it seems that any IOS version before 9.3.1 was giving this issue. Updating the phones have given all of my users access to the mobile app. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether any valid security role is given to the user..